# Como resolver "An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"?

Tags: python, api

Olá,

Estou fazendo uns testes simples para integração da API Gateway com DynamoDB, neste momento consigo fazer um GET e um POST usando o POSTMAN e o GET no python, porém nao consigo fazer o POST no Python, eu estou com um erro de

> One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not
>   contain an empty string

(retorna da AWS) porém nao consigo verificar o que está indo vazio sendo que o corpo da solicitação é o mesmo que uso no POSTMAN.

Alguem ja passou por isso ou faz alguma ideia se pode ser algum parametro errado no python ?

segue tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import requests
import json

###################################################
####ETAPA - CHAMADO API PARA POST##################
###################################################
print('10º ETAPA - CHAMADO API POST')

payload = [
            {
            "id": 10,
            "cont_id": "Monday",
            "idade": 15,
            "name": "Test with python",
            }
          ]
print(str(payload))
try:
  #chamar API POST
  url = 'https://bswv8.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/gravar'
  print('URL API Post: ', url)
  headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
  response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
  print(response.text)

except Exception as e:
  print('ETAPA: ERRO ac chamar API para o POST')

finally:
  print('ETAPA: Chamada a API POST bem sucedido')
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Abs

Comment: Por favor, edite a questão e coloque seu código como código, não como imagem (cole aqui e use o botão `{}` para formatar.  Faça o mesmo com a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: OI @jsbueno. Feito e obrigado pela orientação..

Comment: Duas coisas: 1) seu JSON não está corretamente formatado (tem uma vírgula após o último parâmetro - depois de "Test with python"); 2) você já fez o teste tentando passar `data=payload` ao invés de `json=payload`?

Comment: Oi @MuriloSitonio, obrigado pela resposta. Tentei trocar o 'json=payload' para 'data=payload' mas o erro continua o mesmo, falando que estou passando string vazia, mesmo depois de ter tirado a virgula conforme sua orientação. Na verdade quando eu altero para 'data=payload' ele nao nem consegue chegar na API, ou seja, nem tenho o retorno da string vazia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem parar nessa dificuldade, consegui fazer meu código funcionar tirando os colchetes e mantendo apenas as chaves, no momento em que estou preparando o arquivo json:

ficou:

```
payload = {
        "id": 10,
        "cont_id": "Monday",
        "idade": 15,
        "name": "Test with python",
          }
```

Comment: E entendeu por que isso resolveu o problema?

Comment: Não, mas creio que usando os colchetes o dynamoDB identifica alguma string vazia (esse era o erro). O que faz sentido pois o mesmo layout usado no postman e na propria ferramenta da AWS funciona, a unica diferença era os colchetes para montar o arquivo json no python. Mas se alguém tiver uma explicação melhor, eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Com colchetes você define uma lista de objetos, mas o dynamoDB espera apenas um objeto.

Comment: Boa @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado por resumi e deixar claro ! Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o post já tem um tempo mas me deparei com um problema e lembrei da sua resposta. Preciso enviar um json unico com varios objetos mas o Dynamodb nao aceita, teria algum material para me encaminhar ? não encontro nada relevante.Abraços.,